# Apache default ServerRoot on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, apache

I accidentally changed my ServerRoot value in **httpd.conf** and now I keep getting errors when I run `$sudo apachectl configtest` as the modules fail to load. What value should I put for ServerRoot ?

Comment: Do you have a file /etc/httpd.conf.bak? if so you might look there.

Comment: no, there is no such file